# How can I set the Teams default meeting settings so that the video + microphone are always turned off by default?

Tags: android-10, samsung-galaxy-s-9, microsoft-teams

How can I set the Teams default meeting settings so that the video + microphone are always turned off by default?

I use MS Teams on Android 10 with Samsung Galaxy S9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use teams daily both on Android and Desktop. There are no settings options for these. (Why, I have no idea) [There have been plenty of requests for it...](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/teams-mute-by-default-when-entering-a-meeting/979e5882-3ffa-45f2-8436-e996056d1d5d)

Teams will automatically mute you if there are 5+ users already in the meeting.

As far as video goes, it appears teams takes the default from your previous meetings. My video isn't automatically set to on when I join meetings anymore. Make sure you select video off in the screen that pops up before you join the meeting. That setting should take effect then.